# How to list file in Terminal showing Content Created date/time

Tags: macos, command-line

Picture (jpg) info has 3 dates/times: Created, Modified and Content Created
How can I list the files in the Terminal showing Content Created, ls with any option only shows Created.

For info, I have a large amount of pictures taken by the kids from their travels, the only way to put them together chronologically is to sort them by the Content Created date/time.

Comment: What does "put them together" look like? Finder allows you to sort by filesystem creation date but I am guessing you have some reasons why you want this to be done in the terminal app or with a command-line tool...

Answer (score 3):

For photos `mdls` is the way to get at the detailed metadata.

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate /path/to/file.jpeg
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2022-11-14 14:57:22 +0000
```

You can choose other names like the filesystem creation date instead of the image creation date. For the image above, here are the dates I have on my Mac for an image I exported to the desktop from my iCloud photo stream of an  iPhone image.

```
kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 2022-11-14 14:57:22 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate         = 2022-11-14 14:57:22 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded                       = 2022-11-15 01:42:29 +0000
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate             = 2022-11-15 01:42:29 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate                  = 2022-11-15 01:42:29 +0000
kMDItemLastUsedDate                    = 2022-11-15 01:42:29 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to list the files in a directory with their ContentCreationDate,
navigate to the directory. The command uses ksh style extended globs. If your shell is `ksh` then you need to do nothing. If your shell is `bash` then you need to set the extended glob option-

```
 shopt -s extglob
```

If your shell is `zsh` then set the kshglob option

```
 set -o kshglob
```

The command is

```
 mdls -n kMDItemDisplayName -n kMDItemContentCreationDate -raw -nullMarker '-' +(*.jpg|*.JPG) | tr '\0' '\n' | paste - -
```

Comment: That `mdls` command is excellent - thanks so much for the answer +1 indeed

Comment: Thanks @bmike, I ‘m not  quite sure why it got down voted.